# Why does a spring boot query produce a command with limit 2 in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-jpa, mongodb-query

Given the following Spring boot pom

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

**And the following java declaration:**

```
  @Id
  @JsonProperty("distributor_product_id")
  private String distributorProductId;
```

**And repository find query:**

```
JsonWebsiteContentPreviousUrlKey findByDistributorProductId(String distributorProductId);
```

I get following in the mongod log where **"limit": 2**

```
{
    "t": {"$date": "2023-08-01T01:18:47.726+00:00"},
    "s": "I",
    "c": "COMMAND",
    "id": 51803,
    "ctx": "conn92",
    "msg": "Slow query",
    "attr": {
        "type": "command",
        "ns": "database.JsonWebsiteContentPreviousUrlKey",
        "command": {
            "find": "JsonWebsiteContentPreviousUrlKey",
            "filter": {"_id": "RAED-358ST-0264"},
            "limit": 2,
            "$db": "province",
            "lsid": {"id": {"$uuid": "03818b43-cfda-4840-ba65-7f27155951e6"}}
        },
        "planSummary": "IDHACK",
        "keysExamined": 1,
        "docsExamined": 1,
        "cursorExhausted": true,
        "numYields": 1,
        "nreturned": 1,
        "queryHash": "740C02B0",
        "queryFramework": "classic",
        "reslen": 395,
        "locks": {
            "FeatureCompatibilityVersion": {"acquireCount": {"r": 2}},
            "Global": {"acquireCount": {"r": 2}},
            "Mutex": {"acquireCount": {"r": 1}}
        },
        "storage": {"data": {
            "bytesRead": 132421,
            "timeReadingMicros": 129965
        }},
        "remote": "35.182.242.10:36542",
        "protocol": "op_msg",
        "durationMillis": 130
    }
}
```

Why wouldn't the limit be 1 based upon the above java code?

Does this mean that with each query the database is looking for a second possibility?

What code adjustment is required to make the limit 1.

Regards
Conteh